# Passing Dataframes to a ranged loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many `Dataframes`, all of them have key named `NIM`. I put those `Dataframes` names on a list. Just for an example, this is the list `['parsed_data_id99', 'parsed_data_id100']`. Each items on the list is a `Dataframe` name. `parsed_data_id99` itself is a `Dataframe` and so is `parsed_data_id100`. Why do I make it into a list? because there would be many `Dataframes` made and the numbers of the `Dataframes` is always changing, so I'm trying to automate the process dynamically. One of the process is merging all of the `Dataframes` based on that list. So far, this is what I've got but I don't know how to pass the `Dataframe` itself instead of only the `Dataframe` names which will result output of string. Is there anyway to pass the `Dataframe` to this loop?

```
parsed_data_id100 = {'NIM': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'art_score': [10,8,7]}
parsed_data_id99 = {'NIM': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'math_score': [5,6,9]}

parsed_data_id100 = pd.DataFrame(data=parsed_data_id100)
parsed_data_id99 = pd.DataFrame(data=parsed_data_id99)

list_parsed_df = ['parsed_data_id99', 'parsed_data_id100']
```

```
loop = len(list_parsed_df)-1
merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(loop):
    if merged_df.empty:
        temp = 'list_parsed_df[{i_p}]'.format(i_p=i)
        exec('merged_df = '+eval(temp))
    if not merged_df.empty:
        merge = 'merged_df.merge(list_parsed_df[{i_p}+1], how = "left",on = "NIM")'.format(i_p = i)
        exec('merged_df = '+eval(merge))
```

**SOLUTION**

Based on CaptainK's accepted answer below, I modified a bit his answer and this code below solves my problem

```
merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(loop):
    if merged_df.empty:
        temp = 'list_parsed_df[{i_p}]'.format(i_p=i)
        exec('merged_df = '+eval(temp))
    if not merged_df.empty:
        if isinstance(merged_df, pd.DataFrame):
            temp = 'list_parsed_df[{i_p}+1]'.format(i_p=i)
            exec('temp = '+eval(temp))
            if isinstance(temp, pd.DataFrame):
                merged_df = merged_df.merge(temp, how = "left",on = "NIM")
            if not isinstance(temp, pd.DataFrame):
                print('ERROR : temp {type} is not dataframe'.format(type=type(temp)))
        if not isinstance(merged_df, pd.DataFrame):
            print('ERROR : merged_df {type} is not dataframe'.format(type=type(merged_df)))
```

Output :

```
In  : merged_df.columns
Out :Index(['NIM', 'math_score', 'art_score'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Can you give a simple data example? And maybe use ```pandas.eval```.

Comment: I have edited my question with data example and `pandas.eval` @Johnny

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep pointers to those DataFrames themselves in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using eval().

```
data = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(eval('df'))
```

Here even though 'df' is a string, eval will evaluate the expression and if the expression is a legal Python statement, it will be executed. In your example, you can do something like:

```
if merged_df.empty:
    temp = 'list_parsed_df[{i_p}]'.format(i_p=i)
    print('merged_df = ',eval(temp))
if not merged_df.empty:
    temp = 'list_parsed_df[{i_p}]'.format(i_p=i)
    merged_df = merged_df.merge(eval(temp), how = "left",on = "NIM")
```

Comment: `TypeError: exec() globals must be a dict, not str` in line `exec('merged_df = ',eval(temp))`

Comment: My mistake. I mistyped. It should be without exec. You just want to print merged df right? Updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, the first `if` works, the `merged_df = list_parsed_df[{i_p}]`  works, but the `merged_df = merged_df.merge(list_parsed_df[{i_p}+1], how = "left",on = "NIM"` did not, I just replace your ` , ` with ` + `

Comment: You have follow similar approach for 2nd condition. I updated my answer.